# How to enable mod_deflate on apache

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-deflate

I've come across some article online to enable mod_deflate to gzip files while sending from the server.

For that, I tried to load the `mod_deflate.so` module by adding a line on my httpd.conf

```
LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
```

But it seems the `mod_deflate.so` file is *missing* from the server.

I tried a `find / -name "mod_deflate.so" -print` but it returns no results.

So how do I compile and add `mod_deflate` to my modules directory?

**Update**:

I found out this tutorial at http://streetsmartingit.blogspot.in/2007/11/how-to-compileinstall-moddeflate-into.html?m=1

Step 1 says:

```
Hack apr-config located in the /usr/local/apache2/bin directory so 
the LDFLAGS will have the "-lz" value similar below:
LDFLAGS="-lz"
```

What does 'Hack apr-config' this mean?

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: I'm on Fedora..

Answer (score 2):

Did you build apache from source?  If so, you may need to recompile apache with the option:
  `--enable-deflate`

Comment: I'm not sure about that because I took help from a friend. Can you please elaborate on that - recompiling apache (noob here). Thanks.

Comment: @ptamzz better ask your friend then, he should know what's installed and how.

Answer (score 0):

try run "sudo a2enmod deflate".

Then restart apache.

eg:

$ sudo a2enmod deflate
Enabling module deflate.
To activate the new configuration, you need to run:
  service apache2 restart
$